# Lubuntu 20.04 LTS does not boot on Sony Vaio laptop

Tags: boot, lubuntu, vaio

I recently installed Lubuntu 20.04 LTS on my old (> 10 years) Sony Vaio VGN-CS320J laptop. It installed and started working without a hitch. However I faced a problem when I shutdown my machine. When I powered it up next, the computer started the bootup process, the lubuntu splash screen came up, but a little bit after that, the computer shut down of its own accord. I powered it on again and it booted up as normal (with a slight change -- the first time it went directly to the lubuntu splash screen, the second time it displayed the grub bootloader screen where I chose ubuntu).

This happened twice again. The fourth time, the computer shut down while booting up 3 times in a row (even the second time after I chose ubuntu on the grub bootloader screen) and only on the fourth try did it boot up normally.

Can anyone help me troubleshoot? I have only Lubuntu installed as the OS. Please let me know what other relevant details are needed.

Thanks.

Comment: Also asked at https://discourse.lubuntu.me/t/lubuntu-20-04-lts-does-not-boot-on-sony-vaio-laptop/1840/